# apache mod_rewrite image redirection

Tags: image, apache, mod-rewrite

I have images here...

/images/store/12345/image-0.png

Where 12345 is a product id, 0 can be a single digit number, and png could also be gif or jpg.

On the website I would like to build the image link as

/images/store/12345_$_0.png

where the underscore separates the elents: product id, $ as some arbitrary title  (this-is-my-title-with-dashes-and-numbers-9-but-no-underscores), the image number, and the extension.

Using Apache rewrite engine, how do I direct

/images/store/12345_this-is-my-title-with-dashes-and-numbers-9-but-no-underscores_0.png

to

/images/store/12345/image-0.png

Thanks in advance.

monte

{x:

Comment: Do you want rewrite or redirect the url a to the url b?

Comment: I want a rewrite.  I want Apache to interpret "/images/store/12345_this-is-my-title-with-dashes-and-numbers-9-but-no-underscores_0.png" and show "/images/store/12345/image-0.png" which is the actual file.